# How can I prove the following propositions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I hope you can help me with these:

Prove that:

a)

$$\ A  = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\|(x,y)\|_{\infty}<1\}$$

is an open set.  Where  $\|(x,y)\|_{\infty}=\max\{|x|,|y|\}.$

b)
$$A  = \{\bar{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3:\|\bar{x}\|>2\}$$

is an open set.  Where  $\bar{x}=(x,y,z).$

Comment: Hint: the inverse image of an open set under a continuous function is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $A=\{(x,y):\max (x,y)<1\}$:

If $p=(x,y)\in A$ with $\|p\|_{\infty}=1-r<1$ (with $0<r<1)$ then $|x|<(1-r)\land |y|<(1-r)$.

And the open set $B(p,r)=\{(x',y'):\sqrt {(x'-x)^2+(y'-y)^2}\;<r\}$ is a subset of $A$ because $$(x',y')\in B(p,r)\implies (x'-x)^2+(y'-y)^2<r^2\implies (|x'-x|<r\land |y'-y|<r)\implies$$  $$\implies [\;|x'|=|(x'-x)+x|\leq |x'-x|+|x|<r+(1-r)=1$$ $$ \text {AND }\quad  |y'|=|(y'-y)+y|\leq |y'-y|+|y|<r+(1-r)=1\;]$$ $$\implies (x',y')\in A.$$

Answer (score 1):

1. $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$ is continous.
2. $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=\max\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ is continous.
3. $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(\overline{x})=\lVert \overline{x}\rVert$ is continous.
4. $f:X\to Y$ is continous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for any open subset $U\subseteq Y$.
5. Products and compositions of continous functions are continous.
6. $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b,\infty)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I think that's all you need to prove both statements.